# magento 2.2.1 command is not working

Tags: installation, magento-2.2.1, command

I setup a **Magento 2.2.1** version and I can't give any command by git bash. when I give **Magento** common commands it shows error.

like this:

> $ php bin/magento cache:status Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and
>   7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

what I need do now?

Answer (score 1):

> check your php version and upgrade it to php7 Magento 2.2 required php7. check requirement for magento 2.2 [from here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

Answer (score 0):

**problem is solved.**
i setup composer again and select php latest version from xampp directory during composer setup. now it running smoothly.